# How to automatically boot into Ubuntu? Dual boot with Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Unfortunately I have to use Windows from time to time as some programs are only available for it. 
I have an SSD on my desktop for fast boot up, which is absurd if I have to wait to select my OS every time. Is there an option in GRUB2 (maybe in the grub costumizer) that the computer boots automatically into ubuntu without the timeout, but so that I can still boot into Windows if I need to (for example by holding a key during boot up)?

I know I can change the time out, but I am looking for a solution to not have one at all and still be able to boot into Windows.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So change the timeout "to not have one at all ", and hold Shift to see the menu if needed.

Comment: So if I hold shift while booting the grub menu shows? If so thanks a lot!

Comment: It should, try it.

Comment: My UEFI's fast boot has settings to allow time, so I set it to 3 sec so I could get into UEFI menu if needed. I also set grub to 3 sec so I had time to get into it also. Otherwise if you have issues, you may have major issues getting into UEFI or grub to change boot. But now my boot is 6 sec longer.

Comment: I am a bit late with my answer, but I tried setting the timeout to 0, which just resulted in no change at all, -1 is no time out at all (meaning it stays until you select smth) How do I get rid of it?